# Python 3 NameError when Using variable in 'if' condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple program for 'Stone Paper Scissor', it's just a beginner level code, but I am facing `NameError` for a variable that I defined and using that variable for a condition of `if`. I am using Python 3.I am posting the program I wrote here:

```
player1count = 0
player2count = 0
print("Make a Choice: \n1.Stone\n2.Paper\n3.Scissor")
player1 : int(input("Player 1 plays "))
player2 : int(input("Player 2 plays "))
while (True):
    if player1 is 1 and player2 is 3 or player1 is 2 and player2 is 1 or player1 is 3 and player2 is 2:
        player1count += 1
        print(player1+" beats "+player2)
    elif player2 == 1 and player1 == 3 or player2 == 2 and player1 == 1 or player2 == 3 and player1 == 2:
        player2count += 1
        print(player2 + " beats " + player1)
    else:
        continue
    if(player1count == 5):
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
        break
    elif(player2count == 5):
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
    else:
        continue
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Make a Choice: 
1.Stone
2.Paper
3.Scissor
Player 1 plays 1
Player 2 plays 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Study/Python/StonePaperScissor.py", line 7, in <module>
    if player1 is 1 and player2 is 3 or player1 is 2 and player2 is 1 or player1 is 3 and player2 is 2:
NameError: name 'player1' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Could you write the full error message you're receiving please?

Comment: `is` is not `==`.

Comment: `player1 : int(...)` is a type definition, not an assignment.

Comment: @samwalton I have posted the output itself

Comment: @EliKorvigo Oh yeah, thanks , what a silly error, I didn't even realised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting the error you say when I run your code, however I did get other errors:

```
player1 : int(input("Player 1 plays "))
player2 : int(input("Player 2 plays "))
```

should be

```
player1 = int(input("Player 1 plays "))
player2 = int(input("Player 2 plays "))
```

You also have `print(player2 + " beats " + player1)`. `+` is used for string concatenation, which is when you stick one string on the end of another. However, `player1` and `player2` aren't strings. You need to use `,` instead of `+` or do `str(player1)` and `str(player2)`.

Making those changes to the code you supplied, my output just spams `x beats y`, which is due to an error in your code logic.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize, it was a silly basic error, Thanks a lot, Program runs fine now

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're trying to assign the input values to those variables, please use assignment operator.

```
player1 = int(input("Player 1 plays "))
player2 = int(input("Player 2 plays "))
```

Brownie points :

1. As pointed out in another answer there is bug in print statement too, you're trying to concat int and string. Do something like `print(str(player1) + " beats " + str(player2))`
2. And maybe you need to take the inputs inside the loop.

Working code/demo : https://repl.it/repls/QuintessentialWittyAbilities

Comment: I tried making those changes, the error persists

Comment: It's working fine for me, check here https://repl.it/repls/QuintessentialWittyAbilities

Comment: got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `player: type` is just a *type hint*. It doesn't actually *do* anything, it's there to help readability and external tools for code analysis. It also does not declare the variable, as in static language.

In python, to declare the variable, you have to assign a value to it. So

```
player1: int = int(input("Player 1 plays "))
```

to use both the type hint and the value assignment.

Note: You want `player1==1`, instead of `player1 is 1`. `is` checks if they are the same object, not if they are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it, sorry it was a silly mistake, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since you got the answer you were looking for, i will give you a tip to shorten the code if you want. If you assign the values 0,1,2 to Rock, Paper, Scissors, then your if statements can be greatly simplified as follows:

You take the value from the computer's choice (ex. Scissors = 2) and from it you subtract the value of your choice (ex. Paper = 1). Now whats left of the subtraction determines the outcome.

Make 2 lists, A=[-1,2] and B=[1,-2]

```
If outcome=0: draw
If outcome in B: you lose
If outcome in A: you win
```

This probably works with any series of values you give to the choices, so long as they are linear (ex. 7,8,9)